# One strong recommendation over one strong and another very short but still strong

Tags: recommendation-letter, undergraduate, internship, canada, india

I am applying for an undergraduate internship that requires at least one and at most 2 recommendation letters.

I have two recommendation letters:

- One with a prof. who knows me personally for a year. He has written a very strong recommendation letter (about 1.5 page). (He has mentioned my performance as top 2% of all the years he has offered a course and have also talked about an internship which I undertook under him)
- The second recommendation is from a prof. who doesn’t know me so well outside class. He has mentioned I got a A+ in his course and I’m interested in the specific topic I am applying for the internship but neither of which sound enthusiastic. The letter is about half a page. It doesn’t go deep into my strengths.

Also, both the prof. work in areas related to my internship projects and both of them are from a reputed university.

I have a feeling the second letter can easily overshadow the first one even though it's kind of strong (but not near 25% of my 1st recommendation letter)

In such a situation should I apply with both the recommendations or only the first one?

Comment: You read the letters? That implies this isn't the US, what country are you in?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- India. Also, the internship (mitacs) allows to either have confidential letters by the prof or upload directly by the student.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-, I doubt the tag [tag:india] is really needed here.

Comment: @Buffy Agree. It might even cause confusion considering the application is not for India.

Comment: Well, then where is it for?

Comment: @Buffy LoRs vary immensely by culture. Who knows what a short LoR tells an Indian academic (or whatever country)?

Comment: @AzorAhai the host country must be Canada, since Mitacs is a Canadian internship program.

Comment: Anyone reading the letter would figure out the second prof wasn't as invested into writing it and likely didn't work with you as closely as the first, which is the case. How does that make including it a bad thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the second letter isn't very strong, but at least it supports the recommendation of the other letter. So, it implies some consensus about your abilities, which is a plus.

Your call, of course, but I see no reason not to send both.